# See which function is getting called

Tags: c#

Now that I can see all the classes and function calls in a dll, is there a way I can find out which function is getting called when I click a button in the application that is running on my desktop?  This is a third party app, not one that I wrote.

Comment: Download [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded it.  I have the program running.  How can i use it to tell me the function call used when i click a button in the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to attach a debugger to the running application. There are a number of available ones. Without source or symbols however you will only be able to see the IL as it executes, which will not be the normal C# code you are used to.

Comment: thanks.  would it tell me the name of the functions or anything i would recognize from Visual Studio?

Comment: There would be recognizable function names in there, yes.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you recommend a debugger to use?

Comment: Thinking about it, you likely could just review the code at rest if you disassembled it, check out ilspy and see if you can figure out what your wanting without resorting to full on debugging. If not, I use a tool called IDA that has an evaluation version available

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, this is a 3rd party application - not one that I wrote.  I am trying to find out what function calls are being made when I click one of their buttons.

Comment: I hear ya. Ilspy let's you see that by disassembling the executable or assembly